# Dealing with big training data

Tags: tensorflow

I am writing to ask the principle of how to feed a big training data to a tensor flow model. My training data is hosted in csv file(s), and basically I am using the below code to load data in queue.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([...])
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, line = reader.read(filename_queue)

line = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=default)
label_batch, feature_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([label, feature], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=512, min_after_dequeue=256,  num_threads=8)
```

My experiment as below:

- Exp#1: a single file which 140G of size. my program got "killed", guessing OOM.
- Exp#2: split the big file into 340 small ones. program worked, but GPU utilized almost => 0%, from tensor board items in batch queue getting smaller.

I think in #2 loading data into queue is bottleneck, but I have already using 8 threads to load data. Although a sample in training data is as big as 224*224*3 features, I don't think it should be so slow just loading 512 of them into 16GB memory.

Any one can shed some lights on it? What should I do next? convert csv to binary?

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed convert your files to tensorflow binary format (.tfrecords) and load your data online. Refer to [this tutorial](https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/) to see how to see it through.

Comment: It certainly worked for me. Writing the binary takes time but then feeding examples to your optimizer or whatever is very memory efficient (and blazingly fast).